# Login error in vb.net during execution in connecting with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
Private Sub submit_btn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit_btn.Click

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server= DESKTOP-56RQL1O\SQLEXPRESS; Database = studdb;Integrated Security = true")

    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO student_register (name, regno,dob,blood,gender,course,phone,email,photo,fname,foccupation,mname,moccupation,address,state1,country1,annual_income,alter_email,alter_phone,tenth_institute,tenth_per,tenth_year,plustwo_intitute,plustwo_per,plustwo_year,degree_university,degree_per,degree_year,college_name,state2,country2) Values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "'," & DateTimePicker1.Value & ",'" & blood_combo.Text & "','" & gender_combo.Text & "','" & course_combo.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','@photo','" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & states_combo.Text & "','" & country_combo.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & TextBox11.Text & "','" & TextBox20.Text & "','" & TextBox16.Text & "','" & TextBox13.Text & "','" & TextBox19.Text & "','" & TextBox18.Text & "','" & TextBox21.Text & "','" & TextBox15.Text & "','" & TextBox17.Text & "','" & TextBox22.Text & "','" & TextBox14.Text & "','" & state2_combo.Text & "','" & country2_combo.Text & "')"

    Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)
    connection.Open()

    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    If (command.ExecuteNonQuery().Equals(1)) Then
        MsgBox("Information stored in database")
    Else
        MsgBox("Not stored in database")
    End If
    connection.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

This is my code for save button. But when I execute this, I am getting an error on the `connection.open()` line of code:

> Cannot open database "studdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-56RQL1O\AARTI PRAMOD'.

Please help me with this.

Comment: There is a trick to check the connection string by creating a text file and rename with extension .UDL, then, open the file and follow the wizard, it will create the connection string, to see it just need to open the .UDL file with Notepad. You can also paste the connection string into the .UDL with Notepad and open with double-click and test it.

Comment: I **strongly** suggest you learn how to parametrise your queries. The section `Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO... Values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "',..."` is terrifyingly open to injection. You need to stop writing code like that, now. What you have there are several major security flaws just waiting to be exploited.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using VB.NET. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO student_register Values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "',............................................)"

  i changed my code to this and also checked with .UDL , even then im getting the same error.

Comment: Regarding using `&` in the comment above, after being advised about SQL injection attacks: You need to use Sql Parameters rather than string concatenation to avoid that vulnerability (and SQL syntax errors). Also note that SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable so each should be in a `Using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. And you are calling `ExecuteNonQuery` twice, so it will try to insert twice. You need to store the result from the first time you call it.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot open database "studdb" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-56RQL1O\AARTI PRAMOD'.

This *normally* means that the target database doesn't exist.  So using [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) connect to the SQL Instance and verify that the database exists and that you can access it.